# awk passing shell variables through awk commands

Tags: shell, awk, getline

In an .xml file , I have some information:

```
 <var name="site1">
     <location lat="45.4558" lon="-98.4131" ht="422.0"/>
 </var>
 <var name="site2">
     <location lat="35.1497" lon="-106.8239" ht="1814.0"/>
 </var>
 <var name="site3">
     <location lat="36.9839" lon="-77.0075" ht="78.0"/>
 </var>
```

And I would like to extract the line after I search for 'sitex'. This is easily done with:

```
 awk '/site1/{getline;print}'
```

which, would correctly output:

```
 <location lat="45.4558" lon="-98.4131" ht="422.0">
```

Now if I want to get the lat information, I am able to do this with the complete line:

```
 awk '/site1/{getline;print}' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d \" -f2
```

Which would produce 45.4558, correctly.

Now if I want to pass a variable into awk which can be done with the '-v' command, I have something that looks like below:

```
 locc="site1"
 awk -v var="$locc" '/var/{getline;print}' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d \" -f2
```

However, this produces nothing (i.e., no output). What might the issue be here? If I simply try:

```
 awk -v var="$locc" 'BEGIN{print var}'
```

I get site1 as output. Therefore, it is correctly loading in the string I pass, but not parsing through the information correctly.

Comment: This isn't an appropriate job for getline, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
var="site1"
awk -v val="$var" 'index($0,val){found=1;next} found{print;found=""}' Input_file
```

To get only specific value try following.

```
awk -v val="$var" 'BEGIN{FS="[\"=]"}index($0,val){found=1;next} found{print $3;found=""}' Input_file
```

Output will be `45.4558` for above command.

Comment: What you have provided prints out the line correctly, but am unable to implement the awk command to print only column2 and then the cut command. Therefore, this could work to pass as a variable then I can echo this afterwards to get what I need unless something in one line can achieve this.

Comment: @M.Simpson, Sure, please try my edited solution and lemme know if that helps you?

Comment: To use a set of characters in a regexp (including a FS), `["=]` is a bit clearer and definitely more easily extensible to add other characters to than `"|=`. Consider the more general case of writing `[abcde]` vs having to put a `|` between every pair with `a|b|c|d|e`.

Comment: @EdMorton, Sure Ed sir, that's true. I have made the changes now, thank you sir for guidance here, cheers.

Comment: I really just meant change it to `-F'["=]'` but that's fine too.